# Why do so many languages have both an alveolar "light L" [l] and a velarized "dark L" [ɫ] allophone?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, phonemes, allophones, laterals

Various dialects in all three of [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Sonorants), [Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Further_notes), and [Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_phonology#Sonorants) have accents that contain velarized L allophones, which are sometimes known as “dark L’s”, at the syllable coda.

#### Why is this?

There are two different L allophones: a “light L” [l] is pronounced more at the front of the mouth while a “dark L” [ɫ] is pronounced more at the back of the mouth.  For example:

- In some English dialects, the words *light* [lʌɪt] and *lit* [lɪt] have “light L’s” at the start, while the words *occult* [əˈkʰʌɫt] and *full* [fʊɫ] have “dark L’s” at the end of the syllable.
- In some Portuguese dialects, the words *ler* [leɾ] ‘read’ and *libra* [ˈliβɾɐ] ‘pound’ both start with light L’s, but the words *fácil* [ˈfasiɫ] ‘easy’ and *mal* [maɫ] ‘bad’ both end with a dark L in those Portuguese dialects that do this, although those same words in Spanish always have only a light L.

[Wikipedia mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_lateral_approximants):

> In a number of languages, including most varieties of English, the phoneme /l/ becomes velarized in certain contexts, a sound often called "dark l". Some languages, like many North American dialects of English, may not have a "clear" /l/ at all, or use it only before front vowels (especially [i]).
>
> The velarized alveolar lateral approximant (dark l) is a type of consonantal sound used in some languages. It is an alveolar, denti-alveolar, or dental lateral approximant, with a secondary articulation of velarization or pharyngealization. The regular symbols in the International Phonetic Alphabet that represent this sound are ⟨lˠ⟩ (for a velarized lateral) and ⟨lˤ⟩ (for a pharyngealized lateral), though the dedicated letter ⟨ɫ⟩, which covers both velarization and pharyngealization, is perhaps more common.

How does this phenomenon arise phonologically, and why do native speakers of languages in which this occurs not consider those distinct phonemes? Is this a property that the physical and acoustic characteristics of the buccal cavity lend themselves to naturally, or is it instead some sort of mental adaptation that occurs only in certain cultures?

Are there any languages that have both kinds of L — meaning alveolar or “light” or “clear” on the one hand versus velarized or “dark” on the other hand — as distinct phonemes with minimal pairs rather than as mere allophones?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=light+l+dark+l

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’ve added examples in English and Portuguese where this happens (also happens in Catalan), which you can compare with Italian and Spanish where it does not happen. For Dutch and Hiberno-English the situation is more varied, and I’d have to draw on others’ expertise here.

Comment: How can you compare languages the phonologies of which are completely different? This is three different questions. The answer is different in each case.  However these arose, they arose in different contexts and this question as posed in unanswerable.

Comment: This is like: why do cats, dogs and mice have noses?

Comment: @Lambie In your critter case, they all have noses because their common ancestor had a nose, but in the case of cross-language instability of sonorants/liquids in the codas of languages with no common ancestor that had this property, we should probably look instead to the actual physiology involved. I’m going to migrate this to one of our sister sites that might provide a better language-neutral answer, but I’ll note in passing that [Andalusian Spanish has a similar instability of R/L in the coda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialecto_andaluz#Igualaci%C3%B3n_de_/l/_y_/%C9%BE/_implosivas).

Comment: I'm a native Brazilian Portuguese speaker.  I've always been told we velarize the postvocalic /l/s to a plain semivowel /w/.  I can't tell by ear the difference from the dark L (if any), and I don't know if  this is a difference in description only or if there's a real articulatory distinction between English "full" and our *mal*.  I know that our *mal* definitely "sounds like 'u' (=/w/)" to us (that is, the postvocalic L is perceived by us to be exactly equivalent to a high back semivowel, so that *mal* is an exact homophone of *mau* /maw/ as far as we can tell).

Comment: @boiko There's a slight difference. European Portuguese goes to the dark-L of [ɫ] but Brazilian Portuguese goes further, all the way to [w], sometimes written [u]. [See for example the two pronunciations of *mal*.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mal#Pronunciation_10) *“A consoante /l/ é velarizada nos dialetos europeus. Na maioria dos dialetos brasileiros, /l/ é vocalizado para [w] no final das sílabas.[6] No português brasileiro coloquial, o il átono pode receber o valor de [ju], como em fácil [ˈfasju].”* [wiki ref](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa)

Comment: This is just one example (or three examples, one per language mentioned) of the myriad ways in which the realizing of phonemes depends on their environment. There's no reason to single /l/ out for this.

Comment: As for how we know they're allophones in English, I guess one example of how English speakers "know" that they're the same phoneme can be found in the name of the organization Interpol = "international police". The /l/ at the end of "Interpol" is pronounced, without conscious thought, like any other word-final /l/, regardless of the fact that it's taken from the beginning of the second syllable of "police", where it's realized differently.

Comment: With regard to your last question: Albanian has a contrast between a [phoneme written "l" and a phoneme written "ll"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/555/are-there-minimal-pairs-for-l-vs-ll-in-albanian?rq=1). The latter is described as a "dark l" sound; there was an earlier question on this site asking about its exact realization: [Is the “ll” in Albanian like the sounds in other languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/449)

Comment: And as a further example to your last question: both Irish and Scottish Gaelic have a clear phonemic distinction between ‘dark’ and ‘light’ L (called ‘broad’ and ‘slender’ in descriptions of those languages), which is only to be expected, since both languages have phonemic distinctions between broad (≈velarised) and slender (≈palatalised) variants of _all_ consonants. Some northern dialects also distinguish [fortis and lenis resonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_phonology#Fortis_and_lenis_sonorants), so they have **four** Ls: /l͈ˠ l͈ʲ l͉ˠ l͉ʲ/.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for a functional explanation in the literature, and this apparently isn't a question that has been explored: *why* is the change from clear to dark *l* so common? Dark l has a very low F2, and clear l has a higher F2, so it is unlikely that this is acoustically driven. I suspect that it is related to things necessary to articulate a lateral.

[l] would differ from [t] in that [l] has only a little bit of contact in the front, whereas [l] has contact going back to the molars. It has been observed that in the articulation of [l] (this is from Ladefoged & Maddieson's *The sounds of the world's languages*), the jaw is lower and the tongue is lower, making the lateral opening more possible. (There are other ways, and thus we have palatal [ʎ] as well, where the side cavity is in the front). Lowering the tongue encourages backing (there an empty space in the back where the tongue can easily go, and not much room in the front). So some degree of pharyngealization is probably a natural but not irresistible physiological consequence of what you have to do to achieve a side cavity while maintaining a short alveolar closure.

Unfortunately, it is very difficult to model the degree of physiological necessity of this tongue lowering and backing: there *are* certainly languages with clear *l*. What is empirically unclear, at the moment, is how laterals and plain alveolars compare, articulatorily, in languages which absolutely do not have l-velarization. A physiological comparison tongue retraction and backing in Spanish *l* vs. English clear *l* in maximally non-darkening environments would be informative.

One further factor that is surely relevant is that the velarization effect is most prominent in the syllable coda. It may be that in the onset, duration of *l* is shorter and there is a rapid transition to a more prominent vowel formant, whereas in the coda, what comes after *l* is probably much less prominent acoustically, and the duration of *l* is longer therefore potentially more noticeable.